# How do I define an array of keys of an object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How do I define an array of keys of an object in TypeScript?

Example:

```
const obj = {
  red: 0,
  blue: 1
};

// Doesn't work
const test: keyof obj[] = ['red', 'blue'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you are referring to a value `obj` as a type, which is not allowed. You can get the type of a value with the `typeof` keyword.

Second, `keyof Something[]` will get you `keyof (Something[])`, the keys of the array type, and not `(keyof Something)[]`, which is what you want here. You can use parentheses to fix that.

Putting that together looks like:

```
const obj = {
  red: 0,
  blue: 1
};

const test: (keyof typeof obj)[] = ['red', 'blue'];
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAnApgCYBcMADADTYzwA2ArvqQIyYC+A3JpqJLFPmikAFAGt8ATxAAzGFAkAHfDLhIAlAG0AuqhgaA5AUL6KMfXUb6tHIA)

---

Although most often you'd want to declare a type for `obj` on it's own, so it's easier to use and reference elsewhere.

```
interface MyType {
  red: number
  blue: number
}

const obj: MyType = {
  red: 0,
  blue: 1
};

const test: (keyof MyType)[] = ['red', 'blue'];
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMslBACYBcyIArgLYBG0xyjANrRNXUywL6FCCAPYgAzmGQjGAK2oZseZAF5kREmSrIADABpWHLtQCMhfgG4hoiVMiTqACgDWEdCJhosuCAEoA2gC6qsj+AORaYXrIYUYQYYEWQA)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

```
const test: Array<keyof typeof obj> = ['red', 'blue'];
```